# React elements are removed on state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm supposed to have a modal appear with an image in it. There are next and previous buttons which controls which image you are currently viewing. The modal is rendered in a portal. That in itself is working correctly. However, when I add children, and those childrens are updated, the modal only (not the portal) gets removed from the flow. In the React DevTools, the "isOpen" state of the modal is still set to true. I am using React 17.0.2 with NextJS 12.0.4 and Styled Components 5.3.3.

I have tried:

- memoizing my components (as you can see there are some remnants of those trials) but this did not work
- extracting the state of the modal to the parent and passing it as props and it didn't work either

I know there must be something wrong that I'm doing here so if you could help me find it that would be much appreciated!

Here is the controller where the modal is rendered:

```
import { FC, MouseEventHandler, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Photo } from "services/Images/Images.interfaces";
import { useGetNextPhoto, useGetPhotos, useGetPreviousPhoto } from "state";
import SlideshowContextProvider from "./Context/SlideshowContext";
import SlideShowModal from "./SlideShowModal";

const SlideshowController: FC = () => {
  const photos = useGetPhotos();

  const [currentlyViewedPhoto, setCurrentlyViewedPhoto] = useState<Photo | null>(null);
  const nextPhoto = useGetNextPhoto(currentlyViewedPhoto?.id);
  const previousPhoto = useGetPreviousPhoto(currentlyViewedPhoto?.id);

  const onPreviousRequest: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setCurrentlyViewedPhoto(previousPhoto);
  };

  const onNextRequest: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setCurrentlyViewedPhoto(nextPhoto);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentlyViewedPhoto(photos[0]);
  }, [photos]);

  return (
    <SlideshowContextProvider
      currentlyViewing={currentlyViewedPhoto}
      onNextSlideRequest={onNextRequest}
      onPreviousSlideRequest={onPreviousRequest}
    >
      <SlideShowModal />
    </SlideshowContextProvider>
  );
};

export default SlideshowController;
```

The SlideshowModal:

```
import { Modal } from "components";
import { FC } from "react";
import SlideshowControlBar from "./SlideshowControlBar";
import SlideshowImage from "./SlideshowImage";

const SlideShowModal: FC = () => {
  return (
    <Modal uniqueKey="slideshow">
      <SlideshowImage />
      <SlideshowControlBar />
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default SlideShowModal;
```

The modal in itself:

```
import Portal from "components/Portal/Portal";
import { FC, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { useRegisterModal } from "state";
import styled from "styled-components";
import useWindowScrollLock from "./hook/UseWindowScrollLock";

interface Props {
  uniqueKey: string;
  isBackgroundOpaque?: boolean;
}

... Styled elements

const Modal: FC<Props> = ({ uniqueKey, isBackgroundOpaque = true, children }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const open = () => setIsOpen(true);
  const close = () => setIsOpen(false);

  const register = useRegisterModal(uniqueKey);
  const isModalOpen = useMemo(() => isOpen, [isOpen]);

  useEffect(() => {
    register({ open, close });
  }, [register]);

  useWindowScrollLock(isModalOpen);

  return isModalOpen ? (
    <Portal>
      <Container>
        <InnerModal>
          <Close onClick={close}>X</Close>
          {children}
        </InnerModal>
      </Container>
      <Background onClick={close} opaque={isBackgroundOpaque} />
    </Portal>
  ) : null;
};

export default Modal;
```